Why is my dogs anus bright pink and moist?
I noticed my dog scooting so I checked her bum and her anus is bright pink and moist. I dabbed her bum with a damp cloth and dried it but it still looks moist. It doesn't smell but I've also noticed black stuff as thin as hairs in her anus? Her bum is usually a pale grayish color.

I really hope that by now you already visited a vet. For significant health issues, you should not wait for opinions from people over the internet.

It might be an infection of the, I think in English it is called, anal glands. Sometimes they lick themselves so much, because there is an excess production of fluids back there. It helps to interrupt them when licking. Another possibility is to put some wound healing cream on it.
